# Odoo mobile framework - BaseModel

Tags: java, android, odoo, odoo-mobile

I am currently building an app using Odoo mobile framework. When I look for the BaseModels java class under the base.addons in my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3qFI.png), I can't find the class just like what the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfuyn.png)
shown. Do I need to add BaseModels class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is available in the [framework-master-update-dpr](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/odoo-mobile-framework/tree/framework-master-update-dpr/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/base/addons) branch.

```
public class BaseModels {
    public static final String TAG = BaseModels.class.getSimpleName();

    public static List<OModel> baseModels(Context context, OUser user) {
        List<OModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new OdooNews(context, user));
        models.add(new IrModel(context, user));
        models.add(new ResPartner(context, user));
        models.add(new ResUsers(context, user));
        models.add(new ResCompany(context, user));
        models.add(new IrAttachment(context, user));
        models.add(new MailMessage(context, user));
        return models;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to add that class, if you want to reproduce the same examples just clone the right branch.

Comment: can  I ask for a help about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830462/ocolumn-with-odoo-functional-in-odoo-mobile-framework