# OColumn with odoo functional in Odoo Mobile Framework not working

Tags: android, odoo, odoo-mobile

I have this OColumn partner_name = new OColumn("Partner", OVarchar.class).setLocalColumn(); in my sale order model class with odoo functional method that depends on partner_id column. I would like to search the partner_name in my list using that column partner_name, but I'm a little confused on how to achieve this. Please needed some help.

This is what I've tried:

BaseFragment

```
  @Override
  public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
      getPartnerIds(row);
      OControls.setText(view, R.id.partner_name,  row.getString("partner_name")); // displays false
      ....
    }
}

  private void getPartnerIds(ODataRow row){
      OValues oValues = new OValues();
      oValues.put("partner_id", row.get("partner_id"));
      saleOrder.storeManyToOne(oValues);
}
```

updated:

I noticed that even though I created

```
 @Odoo.Functional(method = "storeManyToOne", store = true, depends = {"partner_id"})
 OColumn partner_name = new OColumn("Partner", OVarchar.class).setLocalColumn();
```

no column was created.

Updated:
[partner_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLmuA.png) column with odoo functional

Edit: Just place the 'if (type.isAssignableFrom(Odoo.Functional.class)'
before the 'if (type.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(Odoo.api.class))' to have the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `partner_name` field like below:

```
@Odoo.Functional(method="storePartnerName", store=true, depends={"partner_id"})
OColumn partner_name = new OColumn("Partner name", OVarchar.class)
                       .setLocalColumn();

public String storePartnerName(OValues values) {
    try {
        if (!values.getString("partner_id").equals("false")) {
            JSONArray partner_id = new JSONArray(values.getString("partner_id"));
            return partner_id.getString(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "false";
}
```

You can simply get the `partner_name` using:

```
row.getString("partner_name")
```

***EDIT:***

> Note that database is created when you first time run your application, or when you clean your data from app
> setting. You need to clean application data everytime when you update your database column.

If the column was added after the database creation, it will not be added to the corresponding table. This is because the database is not upgraded. To fix this issue you can:

- Clean application data to update your database column
- Remove user account (This will delete database) or reinstall the application to recreate the database.
- Or you can change `DATABASE_VERSION` in `odoo/datas/OConstants` then override `onModelUpgrade` method in sale order model and upgrade the table manually (alter sale order table and add the partner name column using SQL query: `ALTER TABLE sale_order ADD partner_name VARCHAR(100)`).
  When a new sale order is created and synchronized, the partner name should be computed and stored automaticaly.

  I noticed that the partner name was not set for existing records after synchrinization so I added another SQL query to compute and set the value of partner name for old records.

  ***Example:***

  ```
    @Override
    public void onModelUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE sale_order ADD partner_name VARCHAR(100)");
            db.execSQL("UPDATE sale_order SET partner_name = (SELECT name from res_partner WHERE _id=partner_id) WHERE partner_name IS NULL AND partner_id IS NOT NULL");
    }
  ```

***Edit (config):***
using the new configuration you will get the following error (which will prevent creating fields using annotations):

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.odoo.core.orm.OModel.compatibleField(OModel.java:349)
```

***CODE:***

```java
if (type.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(Odoo.api.class)) {
```

Try to remove `.getDeclaringClass()`

***Edit: not all partner names are shown***

There is a `org.json.JSONException` error that happens when it try to convert `partner_id` string to a JSON array.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 12 of [114.0, UH PARTNER]
```

The error happens when it try to convert names containing spaces. To avoid that you can cast `partner_id` string to a list of objects.

In `partnerName` method, replace the following code:

```
JSONArray partner_id = new JSONArray(values.getString("partner_id"));
return partner_id.getString(1);
```

With:

```
List<Object> partner_id = (ArrayList<Object>) values.get("partner_id");
return partner_id.get(1) + "";
```

Comment: I also tried doing that but when I put  row.getString("partner_name") in onViewBind(), it will show as false instead the partner name and when I tried adding partner_name in onCreateLoader() for me to search keywords related to partner_name an error occured stating that 'no such partner_name column'. Also, do I need to call storePartnerName() in BaseFragment class?

Comment: You can check how they used partner name in [Sales](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/addons/sale/Sales.java) list and how they declare it in [SaleOrder](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/addons/sale/models/SaleOrder.java#L78) model. Maybe something is missing in the list view.

Comment: I added these lines in onViewBind() ->  if row.getString("partner_name").equals("false")) {
            OControls.setGone(view, (R.id.partner_name));
        } else {
            OControls.setVisible(view, R.id.partner_name);
            OControls.setText(view, R.id.partner_name, row.getString("partner_name"));
        }   but it seems that setGone is triggered and doesn't show the partner name, trying also to onCreateLoader no such column partner_name error occured

Comment: If you added the partner name after you installed the application, the column will not be created, check my edit.

Comment: The ''no such column: partner_name"  error was still shown though I reinstalled the app/clear caches/clean app's data and also adding the lines from the example onModelUpgrade() and changing the database version but still an error "no such column: partner_name" appeared.

Comment: Please share a minimum example to reproduce that issue.

Comment: I added the new OColumn just like the above examples. I also added your examples in onModelUpgrade() and database version. After all I did those changes, I uninstall and reinstall the app. After the data was synced in list view, the part where the data should display the partner name showed as false. I tried also adding partner name in onCreateLoader() like this  where += " client_order_ref like ? or partner_name like ?"; and when I try to search using partner name an error occured stating that "no such column: partner_name"

Comment: If you reinstall the application, you don't need to override `onModelUpgrade()`. Declaring the  `partner_name` column in models is enough to add the column to the database.

Comment: If I don't add a the odoo functional in partner_name column just a normal declaration, a column was being created with null values but when I add the odoo functional, there's no column being created/added.

Comment: I added the `partner_name` as described above and the column was created and I could use the filter. When you use `setLocal()`, it means that the column will not be available on the server and it will be excluded when handling the result of the synchronization. Please try to add the same column on a clean version of the framework

Comment: I tried using the clean version of the framework from github, add the partner_name column and it's functional but row.getString("partner_name") in listview still showed as false, I checked the table but there's no column created for partner_name. I reinstall again and add the onModelUpgrade() example hoping it will work but still the same output. I don't know why it's not working and what causes it not to work.

Comment: Please share the clean version, I want to reproduce the same bug.

Comment: This is the v2.3.0 of the framework https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework.git

Comment: I need the version you modified, to try it with your modification. I used the same version to add a similar field and it worked.

Comment: https://github.com/Plexus-byte/sample this repo has two branches, the master branch is still using lower versions of compiledSdkVersions and classpath dependencies, the partner_name column was created but only few are shown as partner name mostly it shows false, the second branch is where the versions are upgraded and I enabled android.enableJetifier & android.useAndroidX, but when I tried running it, no column was create. Is this because of upgrades to newer versions that's why no column was created while using odoo ffunctional?

Comment: In my recent commits, there's  no partner_name column created, sqlite error for partner_name.

Comment: You did not update the OModel compatibleField method, you should get the same error.

Comment: I've seen the edits in master branch files, when I tried running the app, got the same error, no such column: partner_name. Is the odoo functional only work in older versions?

Comment: I have made the changes to the `implementation_gradle` branch. The `partner_name` was created successfully.

Comment: It worked! a partner_name was created but did all the partner names successfully shown in your partner_name when it was created? In my case some were false. I updated above to show how it looks like.

Comment: Some partner names are  shown as `false`, check my edit.